# What does line 4 syntax read in english?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, comparison-operators

Working on a set of problems and I have come across syntax that I haven't seen before. can someone explain line 4 to me what it reads in English? Is this the standard syntax to communicate range? Why isn't 15 first?

Here is the problem.

1. Define a function that takes a temperature as
   a parameter.
2. returns "Hot" if the temperature is greater than 25
3. Returns "warm" if the temperature is between 15 and 25 including
   15 and 25
4. Returns "cold" if the temperature is less than 15

```
def temperature(temp):
    if temp > 25:
        return 'Hot'
    elif 25 >= temp >= 15:
        return 'Warm'
    else: 
        return 'Cold'
```

Comment: it reads this `the temperature is between 15 and 25 including 15 and 25`

Comment: Python doesn't care which way you turn the comparison, just like it doesn't care whether you say `if a == 15:` or `if 15 == a:`

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operations in python could be [chained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).
You could also use more than two comparison:

```
a, b, c, d, e = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
if a < b < c < d < e < e + a > b + c:
    print('it works!')
```

Comparison operators are lower then arithmetic operations on priority of execution so you don't need () most of the time. You can use different operators (look at last condition above).

In your snipped line 4 is "25 is more or equal to temp and temp is more or equal to 15" or in human English "temp is between 15 and 25 inclusive".

Not important, but in this particular case you do not even need chaining because first condition is covered by first "if":

```
def temperature(temp):
    if temp > 25:
        return 'Hot'
    if temp >= 15:
        return 'Warm'
    return 'Cold'
```